# $\{A_n\}$ is a sequence of connected subspace of $X$ s.t. $A_n \cap A_{n+1} \not= \emptyset$ for all $n$. Show that $\cup A_n$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I know there are several answers to this questions on M.S., but I found them difficult to understand. I also found some answers to this question from some professors' solutions but they are also difficult to understand. I used induction to prove it on my homework, but it's obviously wrong since induction just proves finite union. Could anyone prove it without defining a function?

---

A solution I found is posted below. Does proving $B_n$ is connected by induction on $n$ really prove the infinite union? I still think it just proves finite union.

[image]

Comment: $\emptyset \neq A_{n-1} \cap A_{n} \subseteq B_{n-1} \cap A_n$, not the other way round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP might find a direct proof easier to understand.

---

The OP has a chain

$\tag 1 B_1 \subset B_2 \subset B_3 \dots \subset B_{n} \subset \dots$

of nonempty connected sets the union of which is the same as the union of the $A_n$.

Let $U$ and $V$ be any two disjoint open sets of $B = \bigcup_{\,n \ge 1} B_n$ such that $B = U \cup V$. All the $B_n$ are nonempty connected subspaces, so they are all contained in either $U$ or $V$. Since $B_1$ is contained in every subsequent $B_n$ in the chain, if $B_1$ is contained in, say $U$, then $B_n \subset U$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. But then $U$ must be equal to $B$ and $V$ is empty. Similarly, if $B_1 \subset V$, then $U = \emptyset$.

We have demonstrated that $B$ is connected.

Answer (score 1):

If The union is not connected then there are two open disjoint sets $O_1$ and $ O_2$  such that $A_n \subset O_1$ for some $n\in S\subset  \mathbb{N}$ and  $A_n \subset O_2$ otherwise.

Without loss of generality assume that $A_1 \subset O_1.$

We claim that for some n, $A_n\subset O_1$ and $A_{n+1}\subset O_2.$

Otherwise, every $A_n$ is a subset of $O_1$ which contradicts our assumption.

Thus we have $A_n \cap A_{n+1} = \phi,$ which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know what theorem this solution is referring to, but here's how we can complete the proof:

If $\cup_n B_n$ were disconnected, there would exist nonempty open disjoint subsets $C_1,C_2$ with $C_1\cup C_2=\cup_nB_n$.  Since $B_1$ is connected, it lies in either $C_1$ or $C_2$. Assume $B_1\subset C_1$.  Then since $B_n\subset B_{n+1}$ you can show by induction that $B_n\subset C_1$ for all $n$.  Thus $C_2=\varnothing$, a contradiction.

Comment: TBH, I also don't know what are these theorems. We use induction to prove $B_n \subset C_1$, but doesn't it just prove finite cases? If we don't follow the posted solution, how would you prove it?

Comment: No, if you show that $B_n\subset C_1$ for all $n$, then $\cup_nB_n\subset C_1$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see why $\cup_nB_n\subset C_1$ is true if $B_n\subset C_1$ for all $n$.

Comment: It's basic set theory. Take an element of $\cup_nB_n$.  Then it's in some $B_n$, hence in $C_1$.

Comment: Sorry. I put the "if ..." after "$\cup_nB_n\subset C_1$ is true". So I was asking why is it true that "if $B_n\subset C_1$ for all $n$, then $\cup_nB_n\subset C_1$"?

Comment: I understood what you meant, and that's what I proved.