# Exercise 2, Section 23 of Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof, connectedness

> Let $\{A_n\}$ be a sequence of connected subspaces of $X$, such that $A_n\cap A_{n+1}\neq \emptyset$ for all $n$. Show that $\bigcup A_n$ Is connected.

**My attempt:**

**Approach(1):** Assume towards  contradiction, $\bigcup A_n$ is not connected. Let $P$ and $Q$ form a separation of $\bigcup A_n$. $\forall n\in \Bbb{N}, \exists p_n\in A_n \cap A_{n+1}\neq \emptyset$. So $p_n\in P$ or $p_n \in Q$. Claim: $p_n \in P$, $\forall n\in \Bbb{N}$ or $p_n\in Q$, $\forall n\in \Bbb{N}$. Proof: Assume towards contradiction, $\exists a,b\in \Bbb{N}$ with $a\lt b$(WLOG) such that $p_a\in P$ and $p_b\in Q$. By exercise 1 section 16, $A_n$ is a subspace of $\bigcup A_n$, $\forall n\in \Bbb{N}$. By lemma 23.2, $A_n\subseteq P$ or $A_n\subseteq Q$, $\forall n\in \Bbb{N}$. Since $p_a\in A_a \cap A_{a+1}$, we have $A_a ,A_{a+1} \subseteq P$. $\exists k\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $a+k=b$. $A_{a+1}\cap A_{a+2}\neq \emptyset$, $\exists p_{a+1}\in A_{a+1}\cap A_{a+2}$. Since $p_{a+1}\in A_{a+1}\subseteq P$, $A_{a+2}\subseteq P$. Repeating this process $k$ times. So $A_{a+k}=A_b \subseteq P$. Which contradicts our initial assumption of $p_b\in Q$ (or $A_b\subseteq Q$). Thus our assumption must be wrong. Hence $p_n \in P$, $\forall n\in \Bbb{N}$ or $p_n\in Q$, $\forall n\in \Bbb{N}$. WLOG assume $p_n\in P$, $\forall n$. Let $n\in \Bbb{N}$. $A_n$ and $A_{n+1}$ are connected and subspace of $\bigcup A_n$. Since $p_n\in P$, we have $A_n,A_{n+1} \subseteq P$. So $A_n \cup A_{n+1}\subseteq P$. Since $n$ was arbitrary, $A_n \cup A_{n+1}\subseteq P$, $\forall n\in \Bbb{N}$. Thus $\bigcup_{n\in \Bbb{N}} A_n \subseteq P$. Which implies $Q=\emptyset$. Which contradicts the fact that $Q\neq \emptyset$. **Is this proof correct?** This proof is inspired by Munkres’ proof of theorem 23.3. Can this approach is refined(especially claim part)?

**Approach(2):** Let $f:\bigcup A_n \to \{0,1\}$ be a continuous map. $f|_{A_n}: A_n \to \{0,1\}$ defined by $f|_{A_n}(x)=f(x),\forall x\in A_n$ is a continuous map by theorem 18.2. Since $A_n$ is connected, $f|_{A_n} (A_n)= f(A_n)=\{i_n\}$, for some $i_n\in \{0,1\}$. Since $A_n \cap A_{n+1}\neq \emptyset$, $\exists x_n\in A_n \cap A_{n+1}$. So $f(x_n)=i_n=i_{n+1}, \forall n\in \Bbb{N}$. Let $i_1=i$. Claim: $i_n =i, \forall n\in \Bbb{N}$. Proof: Base case, $i_1=i$ is true. Suppose $i_k=i$ for some $k\in \Bbb{N}$. Then $i_k =i_{k+1}=i$. So $i_{k+1}=i$. By mathematical induction $i_n=i, \forall n\in\Bbb{N}$. Thus $f(\bigcup A_n)=i\in \{0,1\}$, a constant map. Hence $\bigcup A_n$ is connected. **Is this proof correct?**

**Approach(3):** https://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-3/section-23-connected-spaces/problem-2-solution/.

**Approach(4):** [$\{A_n\}$ is a sequence of connected subspace of $X$ s.t. $A_n \cap A_{n+1} \not= \emptyset$ for all $n$. Show that $\cup A_n$ is connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2740594/861687) or [similar proof](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwins86I4aH3AhUk7HMBHbgGC8cQFnoECCAQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcanvas.harvard.edu%2Ffiles%2F1255359%2Fdownload%3Fdownload_frd%3D1%26verifier%3DBK3UeEKLUWpKC0bpBEtNMnLU3TLEV1J1vURwVNjQ&usg=AOvVaw3z2LOC_zR87PnT_66ie7N5).

**Application:** Inspired by https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4385310/861687 proof.

> **Claim:** If $\{ A_n| n\in \Bbb{N}\}$, $A_n$ connected subspaces of $X$ such that $A_i\cap A_j\neq \emptyset, \forall i,j\in \Bbb{N}$, then $\bigcup_{n\in \Bbb{N}} A_n$ is connected.

**Proof:** Condition $A_n\cap A_{n+1}\neq \emptyset ,\forall n\in \Bbb{N}$ is weaker then $A_i\cap A_j\neq \emptyset, \forall i,j\in \Bbb{N}$ , i.e. $A_i\cap A_j\neq \emptyset, \forall i,j\in \Bbb{N} \Rightarrow A_n\cap A_{n+1}\neq \emptyset ,\forall n\in \Bbb{N}$. By exercise 2 section 23, $\bigcup A_n$ is connected.

Comment: Both solutions look good to me.

Comment: Search this site. I'm sure this result has been asked before & there is a very simple short proof. I don't want to risk the wrath of the moderators by answering a duplicate....

Comment: @DanielWainfleet at least I didn’t see any related post in search bar engine.

Comment: Let $F$ be a family of connected subspaces of $X$ such that $A\cap A'\ne\emptyset$ whenever $A,A'\in F.$ Let $B,C$ be open subsets of $X$ with   $B\cup C\supseteq\cup F$ and $\emptyset=B\cap (\cup F)\cap C.$ For each $A \in F$ we have $B\cup C\supseteq A$ and $\emptyset=B\cap A\cap C$, so $A\subseteq B$ or $A\subseteq C.$ Now if $A,A'\in F$ with $A\subseteq B$ and  $A'\subseteq C$ then $\emptyset\ne A\cap A'=B\cap (A\cap A')\cap C\subseteq B\cap (\cup F)\cap C=\emptyset,$ which is absurd. Therefore every $A\in F$ is a subset of $B,$ or every $A\in F$ is a subset of $C.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I vaguely know this definition of connectedness. I’m not use to using that definition of connected space.

Comment: The topological definition is a space  is connected iff it is not the union of two disjoint non-empty open subsets. A subset of a space is connected iff it is a connected space when given the subspace topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach 2 is OK: I'd write

Let $f: \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \to \{0,1\}$ be continuous.
So there exists $i_1 \in \{0,1\}$ so that $f\restriction_{A_1} \equiv i_1$ as $A_1$ is connected. By induction we show $$\forall n: f\restriction_{A_n} \equiv i_1\tag{1}$$ The base case $n=1$ holds by definition now. Suppose it holds for $n$. Then there is some $j \in \{0,1\}$ so that $f\restriction_{A_{n+1}} \equiv j$; let $p \in A_n \cap A_{n+1}$ then $f(p)=i_1$ as $p \in A_n$ and the induction hypothesis holds, and $f(p)=j$ by $p \in A_{n+1}$ and the definition of $j$. So $i_1 = j$ and the statement holds for $n+1$ too, finishing the induction.

$(1)$ immediately implies that $f$ is constant and we're done.